# Showing popup on image click

Tags: model-view-controller, razor-pages, .net-5

I'm using this code to show images.
The problem is that it is showing popup only for the first image and not the rest.
Images are loaded from database so they all have the same id.
Is that the problem or something else?

Code :

```
        if (ViewBag.ReceptiSearchAll != null)
        {

            <div class="col-6 col-lg">
               @foreach (var images in ViewBag.ReceptiSearchImages)
                {                                              

                    if (images.Image != null)
                    {
                        imagePath = images.Image;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        imagePath = images.ImageDefault;
                    }

                    <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 400px;border:none">
                        <div class="row no-gutters">
                            <div class="col-md-12">

                                <img id="imgrec" class="card-img-top" src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(imagePath)" alt="Slika recepta" width="250" height="200">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        }


<script>
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
    var img = document.getElementById("imgrec");
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    img.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

All your images have the same id.

<img id="imgrec" ...

id is meant to be a unique identifier.

**var img = document.getElementById("imgrec");**

For that reason, only your first image gets this.

```
img.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }
```